# DHCP inet address keep disappearing

Tags: networking, dhcp, ifconfig

I'm having trouble with network with Ubuntu embedded on a PYNQ board. By running `ifconfig` I can see that the inet address keeps disappearing and then reappearing. My network interface looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

With static address, I never have this problem. I did a lot of research, but I can't seem to find an answer to this problem.

`ifconfig` output:

[image: ifconfig output]

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using? did you get the interfaces from the file "/etc/network/interfaces" ? did you edit that file manually? if you edit your interface file, and it still changes, then something must be changing it. is this ethernet or wifi?

Comment: It's PynqLinux 3.0, which is based on Ubuntu 22.04. Yes the interface is in the file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0, the file is not changing

Comment: So when you saw it is disappearing, do you you mean the address keeps changing?
or is it dropping the address? also, do you want a static address? can you post the output of `sudo dmesg` to pastebin or something? I would be curious what the physical device is doing. Are you supplying ample power to the device?

Comment: That is not Ubuntu and is off topic on this site.